# Gemfire offers Time To Live for an element?

Tags: gemfire

Like in `EHCache`, we can set maximum time for an element to stay in the cache, after the timeout it will automatically get evicted/removed.

Since I am newbie to `Gemfire`, can any expert share whether this functionality is available in `Gemfire`?

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that data (Region entry) "eviction" is not the same thing as "expiration".

TTI (idle-timeout) and TTL (time-to-live) refer to "expiration" settings where as LRU (and other algorithms like LFU) are "eviction" settings and can be configured with different behaviors (a.k.a. "actions") depending on the application functional requirements and use cases.

See how GemFire [Eviction works](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/latest/userguide/index.html#developing/eviction/how_eviction_works.html) as well as how [Expiration works](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/latest/userguide/index.html#developing/expiration/how_expiration_works.html), and how the 2 settings are configured ([Eviction](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/latest/userguide/index.html#developing/eviction/configuring_data_eviction.html), [Expiration](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/latest/userguide/index.html#developing/expiration/configuring_data_expiration.html)), respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Gemfire does support TTL at the Region and entry level. Have a look at the [docs](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/latest/userguide/index.html#developing/expiration/how_expiration_works.html)